# jQuery accordion automatically move to next accordion div if user hits the tab key on last input

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

After user hits last tab of a form in jQuery UI's accordion how do you get the next div to open and current one to close with the focus on the next input in-line?

Also I am looking for the reverse.  If use types shift tab to go in the opposite direction then I am searching for a way to implement the reverse behavior as well. I.e. close the existing accordion div and open up the next accordion div in line and go to the last input in the div and set focus to it.

Answer (score 4):

You need to bind the Tab key press, on the last input field of a form, to the accordion function to activate the next section:

```
$('#firstform input:text').last().on('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 9) {
        if (!e.shiftKey) {
            var active = $( "#accordion" ).accordion( "option", "active" );
            $("#accordion").accordion( "option", "active", active + 1 );
        }
    }
});
```

You also need to activate the first input box of the next form, using the activate event of the accordion:

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
    activate: function( event, ui ) {
        $("#secondform input:text").first().focus();
    }
});
```

The procedure is similar for the reverse case, as you can see in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mxbax/3/).